# can I add an animation before the default splash screen disappear？

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

I have a question about the splash screen，as we know we can set splash screen by adding 
Default.png” and “ Default@2x.png “ in project without any code,but If I want to add an animation before the splash screen disappear for example a view that appear then fade away  ，how to do it？Thank you very mush！

Comment: This isn't Google, show what you've attempted and someone will help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, as far as I can see, is no.

Apple [discourages that sort of thing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html) in their guidelines, so I doubt it's going to be added any time soon.  Their intent for the launch screen is to be a simple transitional screen the user sees while the OS handles some setup work, and not a "welcome" screen or noticable event.